# Representation of an ellipse as function of point

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, conic-sections, ellipsoids

Has anyone come across this representation of an ellipse:
$\mathcal E := \left\{ x \mid f(x) \leq 0 \right\}$, where

$$ \begin{aligned} f(x) &= x^{\top} c x+2 d^{\top} x + e\\ &=\left[\begin{array}{ll}x \\ 1\end{array}\right]^{\top}\left[\begin{array}{ll}c & d \\ d^{\top} & e\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ 1\end{array}\right]\end{aligned} $$

I have no idea how to derive this from the conventional form:

$$\mathcal E = \left\{x \mid\left(x-x_{c}\right)^{\top} A^{-1}\left(x-x_{c}\right) \leq 1\right\}$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just expand the product  in the second form.

Comment: The matrices in this are $c$ ($2\times 2$) $d, x$ ($1\times 2$) and the mix is $3 \times 3$.

Comment: An ellipse is a curve. It doesn't include the interior, so the ellipse is actually $\mathcal E = \{ x \mid f(x) = 0 \}$

Comment: You forgot $A \succ 0$.